# Mounts of systemd service script disappear

Tags: mount, systemd, startup

I have a systemd service file of the following kind.

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount some special file systems
After=local-fs.target
Before=syslog.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/some-complicated-mounts.sh
ExecStop=/root/some-complicated-umounts.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script `/root/some-complicated-mounts.sh` mounts some file systems.

The service was not working until I added the `RemainAfterExit=yes` statement. Without this statement the mounts that are done by the script seem to disappear, eventhough according to the logs the script is executed successfully.

I would like to know, why I need the `RemainAfterExit=yes` statement and where this behavior is described in the systemd documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This oneshot service will not work without `RemainAfterExit=yes` because systemd will consider that the unit will go inactive as soon as the `some-complicated-mounts.sh` script is finished and, at that point, it will stop the unit, which includes executing the `ExecStop=` command, which will then proceed to unmount the filesystems by executing the `some-complicated-umounts.sh` script.

Using `RemainAfterExit=yes` solves this issue, since the unit is then considered started after the `ExecStart=` command completes and is *kept in an active state*. So the `ExecStop=` command will only execute if the unit is stopped explicitly (with a `systemctl stop` command) or as part of a normal shutdown procedure, when all units are stopped.

---

Regarding documentation, the systemd documentation actually has an example for this exact scenario: see ["Example 3. Stoppable oneshot service"](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#id-1.10.4) on the man page for systemd.service(5). The description for the use case of the example says:

> Similarly to the oneshot services, there are sometimes units that need to execute a program to set up something and then execute another to shut it down, but no process remains active while they are considered "started". [...]
>
> For this, systemd knows the setting `RemainAfterExit=yes`, which causes systemd to consider the unit to be active if the start action exited successfully.

Also contrast that with [Example 2](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#id-1.10.3), which is a oneshot service without an `ExecStop=`.

(Unfortunately the documentation for [`RemainAfterExit=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RemainAfterExit=) itself is too terse and doesn't really go these details. There's probably an opportunity for improvement to the documentation of that option here.)